# Trying to understand an else clause without preceding conditional

Tags: ruby

This code from [Handle Web Requests with Ruby](https://openclassrooms.com/en/courses/4924041-handle-web-requests-with-ruby/5294811-remember-users-with-cookies) appears in the video demo and runs in the video, but I don't see how it could work. The `cookie_parts` "block" ends with an `else` clause that has no preceding `if` or `rescue`.

```
require 'socket'
server = TCPServer.new 8000

PAGES = {
  "/" => "Hi, welcome to the home page!",
  "/about" => "About us: we are http hackers",
  "/news" => "We haven't made much news yet with this server, but stay tuned"
}

PAGE_NOT_FOUND = "Sorry, there's nothing here."

loop do
  session = server.accept
  request = []

  while (line = session.gets) && (line.chomp.length > 0)
    request << line.chomp
  end
  puts "finished reading"

  http_method, path, protocol = request[0].split(' ') # 3 parts to request line

  cookie_header = request.detect { |line| line =~ /^Cookie: / }
  cookie_parts = cookie_header.sub /^Cookie: /, ''
    cookie_parts = cookie_parts.split('; ')
    cookie_parts = cookie_parts.map { |cookie| cookie.split('=') }
    cookies = Hash[*cookie_parts.flatten]
  else
    cookies = {}
  end

  cookies["session_key"] ||= Time.now.to_f
  # nil.to_i returns 0, so if cookie isn't set, count will be 0
  count = cookies["session_count"].to_i
  count += 1
  cookies["session_count"] = count


  if PAGES.keys.include?(path)
    status = "200 OK"
    response_body = PAGES[path]
  else
    status = "404 Not Found"
response_body = PAGE_NOT_FOUND
  end

  session.puts <<-HEREDOC
HTTP/1.1 #{status}
set-cookie:session_key=#{cookies["session_key"]}
set-cookie:session_count=#{cookies["session_count"]}

#{response_body}
This was visit number #{cookies["session_count"]}!
  HEREDOC

  session.close
end
```

Running the same code locally yields the errors I'd expect:

```
server.rb:28: else without rescue is useless
server.rb:57: syntax error, unexpected `end', expecting end-of-input
```

What conditional or block is the `else` supposed to belong to?

Comment: Which is it *supposed* to belong to? Who knows; the original code isn't immediately available. Which is it *likely* to belong to? The part that determines whether or not there are any cookies. My guess is it's missing an `if` like on the `detect` line or something--but you should also be able to figure this out and/or a way around it.

Comment: I know I can make it work. I think I'm just making the mistake of assuming the version in the video edit is what actually ran right after it was shown. Since there's no public repo for it, there's nothing to compare it to.

Comment: Always err on the side of assuming nothing works, especially tutorial code :) But you need to forward to ~5:30, which indeed includes the missing `if` I alluded to above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watch the *rest* of the video, to wit, at ~5:30 you'll see the missing `if` I mentioned in my comment:

```rb
if cookie_header = request.detect { |line| line =~ /^Cookie: / }
  cookie_parts = cookie_header.sub /^Cookie: /, ''
  cookie_parts = cookie_parts.split('; ')
  cookie_parts = cookie_parts.map { |cookie| cookie.split('=') }
  cookies = Hash[*cookie_parts.flatten]
else
  cookies = {}
end
```

Comment: Wow, that's embarrassing. I was so stuck in the loop of "How did he get this code as written to work?" that it didn't occur to me to look past the initial run. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the middle of the code in your question, there is this section

```
cookie_header = request.detect { |line| line =~ /^Cookie: / }
cookie_parts = cookie_header.sub /^Cookie: /, ''
  cookie_parts = cookie_parts.split('; ')
  cookie_parts = cookie_parts.map { |cookie| cookie.split('=') }
  cookies = Hash[*cookie_parts.flatten]
else
  cookies = {}
end
```

There you have an `else` block but there is no `if` condition in front of it. Ruby doesn't know how to handle it and therefore the error message.

I agree that the error message is a bit misleading because an `else` block like that is more likely missing an `if` condition than a `rescue`. But a `rescue` block is also an example in which Ruby allows an `else` like this:

```
begin
  # code that might raise an error
rescue 
  # code that is run when there was an error
else
  # code that is run when there was _no_ error
end
```

Comment: What's puzzling me is that the instructor runs the code exactly as I've posted it, and it worked—when as far as I can see, it should've have. I also don't know why his vim auto-indented the lines after the sub regex. Unless there's something in Ruby I don't understand, I have to assume he edited the video after adding something to the code, but forgot to add it to the cut.